# Why won't any version of IE process this Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, attributes

This is the code, changing a background image for a jQ plugin, Works fine on Chrome, FF, Safari and even my two smart phones. But not IE. Can anyone spot a problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#supersized img").attr({ 
          src: "images/bg2.jpg",
        });
    $("#supersized").attr($("img"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: what happens if you take out the comma after src: "images/bg2.jpg" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE is very strict on its object literal formation.  Many times it does not like you to put a comma after the last property.  So in this instance the comma after your `src` property will give IE fits, most notoriously IE 6 & 7

```
$("#supersized img").attr({ 
          src: "images/bg2.jpg"  //<-- notice no comma after property value because it's the last one.
        });
    $("#supersized").attr($("img"));
});
```

Comment: There's no json here, but you're right about the trailing comma in IE.

Comment: isn't `{ src: "images/bg2.jpg" }` a json object being passed to the `.attr()` ?

Comment: @jondavidjon: Sorry for the delay. No, JSON is a data interchange format whose structure is based on the Object and Array structures in javascript (and as such are easily parsed into javascript), but ultimately JSON data is text. The code here is a javascript object literal. This is an example of an object literal: `{a:"b"}`. This is an example of valid JSON data `'{"a":"b"}'` (notice it is a string), which can be parsed into the first version.

Comment: gotcha, adjusted answer, thanks for following me around and cleaning up after me! ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's a trailing comma in your object literal. This always causes an error in IE browsers.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is not only Internet Explorer related, as I notice only Firefox would execute it without warnings. The reason that object keys suppose to be escaped properly with single or double quotes in your case

```
{ 'src': "images/bg2.jpg" }
```

and also remove coma after image path.

Comment: A key does not need to be in quotes if it is a valid identifier (like src), but you're right about the trailing comma in IE.

Comment: That's not true. Unquoted keys are legal JavaScript in any browser. It's the comma that's the problem.

Comment: well Chrome does not like it and some keys should be escaped to avoid collisions with other default keywords.

Comment: It's true that JavaScript reserved words may not be used as identifiers, but `src` is not a reserved word and Chrome has no problems interpreting `{ src: "images/bg2.jpg" }`.