# ajax not loading on load only explorer 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have a page that loads names into a list using AJAX and I also have a search box. Simple, right?

My page works fine on any browser except ie8, ie8 doesn't load any data when page loads, but when I type something on the search box the ajax start requesting data.

```
$(function () 
{
//Domain Search text box
$('#faq_search_input').keyup(function() {                   
  var textboxVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  show_names(textboxVal);
});



//Here is how I request the data
function show_names(search)
{ 
    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'api-visits.php?search='+search,
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(rows)
          { 
            var list = $("#toggle").append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
              for (var i in rows)
                {
                  var row = rows[i];
                  Dname = row[0];
                  list.append("<li class='ident' id='"+row[6]+"'>"+Dname+"</li>");
                }
           list.push(Dname);
           //Here I do other Not important stuff like calling an image, etc.
    });
}
});

<!--My HTML-->
<div id="tbox">
  Domain Search:
  <input class="reginput"  type="text" id="faq_search_input" />
</div>
<div id="toggle" style="border-top-width: 100px; padding-top: 50px;"></div>
```

On other browsers the data loads fine, is there any special "requests" from IE8 to make my page working? my question is kinda AMBIGUOUS, but what do you think?

Comment: Sounds like the issue may be within the caller, if that function works when you type. Post some more code to give us context.

Comment: Could u post some more code..I mean complete code.

Comment: The `ready` function's code would be helpful.

Comment: I don't see where you expect any data to load.  The only Ajax request is triggered by keyup in the input box, and you indicated that typing in the search box *does* cause IE8 to load data.  What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Your success callback needs a closing bracket:

```
success: function(rows)
          { 
            var list = $("#toggle").append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
              for (var i in rows)
                {
                  var row = rows[i];
                  Dname = row[0];
                  list.append("<li class='ident' id='"+row[6]+"'>"+Dname+"</li>");
                }
           list.push(Dname);
           //Here I do other Not important stuff like calling an image, etc.
          }
```

Comment: His comment indicates he removed irrelevant code - he must've removed the closing bracket here.  If there were something broken like a missing bracket, it wouldn't work in *any* browser, or when he types into the search box.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what is actually his code then? Just guess which parts he omitted? Just so you know, you can have syntactically incorrect javascript run perfectly fine in chrome and firefox, but not in IE. Think about the trailing comma problem that exists in IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846952/why-wont-any-version-of-ie-process-this-javascript